# What GPIO i need to define for efr32fg14 I2C communication

Tags: embedded

UART and SPI i have defined my ports for input and output as follows,but in I2C we have SDA which iss by directional. How to see using the manual shown bellow what kind of gpio we need to define here?
Thanks.

https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/reference-manuals/efr32xg14-rm.pdf

```
  GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortA, 1, gpioModeInput, 0);
  GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortA, 0, gpioModePushPull, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Both I²C bus pins are open drain with an external pullup resistor.

Also called "wired and". Input filter is also probably a good idea:

```
GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortA, 0, gpioModeWiredAndFilter, 1);
```

Comment: Hello Turbo, Were can i read about all the options of GPIO and their meang.I coud not find it in the reference manual.

https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/reference-manuals/efr32xg14-rm.pdf

Comment: Hello Turbo, Were can i read about all the options of GPIO and their meang.I coud not find it in the reference manual.

Why adding a filter is a good idia?
why in UART or SPI we didnt need to use filter?
https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/reference-manuals/efr32xg14-rm.pdf